# How to reset netplan to default in 18.04?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I tried creating a network bridge through Virtual Machine Manager for KVM. Now my Ubuntu network connection **depends** on my Windows KVM being booted.

Since creating this bridge when Ubuntu is booted there is no network connectivity at all, no network icon at the top right corner of the screen, no web pages will load, and I am even unable to access any of my local servers and other computers on the network.

The process to get network connectivity back after a reboot is to open VMM, go to network connections and enable the bridge that I created (it's set to start on boot but it doesn't). However just enabling the bridge isn't enough, still nothing works. It's not until my Windows 10 VM is fully booted that suddenly I have full network connectivity again, and everything works fine.

I don’t know how that happened. But I need to get my Ubuntu networking set back to normal. Then I need to figure out how to properly bridge Ubuntu and KVM

Comment: Anybody have anything? This issue is getting really annoying. Did I not provide enough info? Is there anything else I need to add? I've asked this question on 3 different forums, and noone knows how to restore ubuntus networking to it's default state?

Comment: Silly idea: could it be that the default route got set so it goes through the VM? Check with `traceroute` or `mtr` once the VM is booted.

Comment: As netplan is an Ubuntu invention there will be a lack of knowledge about it.

Comment: I did just run 'traceroute' to '8.8.8.8' and the very first hop was my Untangle firewall. so it doesn't seem like my traffic is going through the VM

Comment: Err, where is your netplan YAML?